# uinavbar add button animation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, core-animation

Currently I am trying to add button to UINavigationBar. Here is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                 animations:^{
                     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0]];
                     searchBar.hidden= NO;
                     searchBar.bounds= CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(searchBar.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(searchBar.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(searchBar.bounds)+50, CGRectGetHeight(searchBar.bounds));
}
                 completion:nil
 ];
```

The problem is no matter what options I set for the animation, the RightBarButtonItem ends up being animated as "Flying from left to right".
Instead I want to have a fade in or something similar animation, watching it fly from left to its position in right is just hideous.

Comment: try transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion: for it.

Comment: that actualy works for the search bar. But the buttons are still not getting animated. If I put "transitionwithview: searchabr" only search bar gets animated and if I put "transigtionwith: self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar" the complete navbar gets animated. Is there a way to animate only the rightbarbuttons too? What should I put in transitionwithview: uiview to make them animate along with searchBar

Comment: i think , in that case you need to use a custom navigation bar(may be view with back uibutton) then you can animation the back button as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to make it ,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];

[UIView transitionWithView:button
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

 }];
```

}

you can try some more code to make it correctly. you can try with `CATransition`.
play with following code, and do tell me when you get success. Good Luck.